Material UI Autocomplete button event listener is always open

I have an MUI V6 autocomplete component like this in my application. I have built it as a reusable component that I use 4 times in the application. The problem I am encountering is that when I click the dropdown button it opens but when I click it again it does not close the dropdown but rather the event loops back to open therefore stuck with a open dropdown unless you focus on a different part of the application. I am wondering if anyone else has experienced that and how did you fix it.
Edit:
A simpler explanation, the popper stays open when the chevron button is pressed rather than reverting to a close state.

If anyone runs into this issues this is the fix that was released by MUI
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/44144
